# Rails, validate maxlength of input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a comment model where I limit the maximum length of a comment like:

```
validates_length_of :comment, :maximum => 500
```

In my view I have input field declared:

```
<%= f.text_area :comment,:as => :text, :maxlength => 500 %>
```

The limit on the input field works as expected, it limits to maximum 500 chars.

However, the model limit does not work as expected. A text of 500 chars with newlines gives a validation error. The model counts newlines as two characters (and possible other characters too). So

This input will work, no newlines:

```
 abc abc abc abc....
```

This will not:

```
abc

abc
.
.
```

Is there a simple way to make validates_length_of to count newlines (and other) as one character?.

===Result1===

I combined the great answers from Jon and Dario and created this:

```
before_validation(:on => :create) do
  self.comment = comment.gsub("\r\n","\n") if self.comment
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsers send newlines from textareas as "\r\n"
Effectively each newline is counted as two chars when using Rails default length validator

So either make a replace method in the controller, or make a custom length validator.

Answer (score 5):

You could use tokenizer option of the length validator, to count only the words, not the line breaks.

```
validates :comment, length: {
  maximum: 500,
  tokenizer: lambda { |str| str.scan(/\w+/) }
}
```

For more information, take a look here: [Active Record Validations and Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html)

Comment: Rails 5.1 deprecated 'tokenizer' option.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
validates :comment, length: {
  maximum: 500,
  tokenizer: lambda { |str| str.scan(/./) }
}
```

This way you get exactly the string size you expect.

This textarea input:

> This is a string with
>
> a line break

leads to this string

> "This is a string with a\r\na line break"

per default the rails validator counts each character and gets a length of 36

```
"This is a string with \r\na line break".length
=> 36
```

If you use the tokenizer with the regexp `/./` you get a result of 35 as you would expect (each character + spaces + 1 newline) because it stripts the `\n` but counts the `\r` instead.

```
"This is a string with a\r\na line break".scan(/./)
=> ["T", "h", "i", "s", " ", "i", "s", " ", "a", " ", "s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g", " ", "w", "i", "t", "h", " ", "a", "\r", "a", " ", "l", "i", "n", "e", " ", "b", "r", "e", "a", "k"]

"This is a string with \r\na line break".scan(/./).count 
=> 35
```

For more information on the string method `scan` see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan

For more information on regexp you could play a little bit with http://rubular.com/

Comment: Rails 5.1 deprecated 'tokenizer' option.